# How to add item to a state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to add a new empty object when a user click Add a new item button. I'm using state method for display the values.

I create the addField() function for doing that but I couldn't fill it.

```
export interface IDetailsPageBindings {
  getFields(): Promise<IFieldDefinition[][]>;
  storeFields(): boolean;
}

export interface IDetailsPageConfig {
  name: string;
  fields: IFieldConfigDefinition[];
}

interface IDetailsPageState {
  fields: IFieldDefinition[][];
  activeFields: {
    key: number;
    fields: IFieldDefinition[];
  };
}

class DetailsPage extends Component<IDetailsPageConfig, IDetailsPageBindings, IDetailsPageState> {
  handleDetailClick(index: number, activeFields: IFieldDefinition[]) {
    this.setState({
      activeFields: {
        key: index,
        fields: activeFields
      }
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.bindings.getFields().then(data => {
      this.setState({
        fields: data
      });
    });
  }

  addField(){
    console.log("clicked")
    return true
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state?.fields) {
      return;
    }
    return (
      <div>
        <Row>
          <Col xs={2} >
            <button onClick={() => this.addField()}>
            Add a new item</button>
          </Col>
          <Col xs={7} >
            <div>
                  {
                    this.state.activeFields?.fields?.map(field => {
                      const config = this.config.fields.find(fieldConfig => fieldConfig.key === field.key);
                      if (!config) {
                        logger.error(`Field config for key ${field.key} not found`);
                        return;
                      }

                      const inputConfig = createTextInputConfig(
                        config.dataType.type,
                        config.displayName || "",
                        false,
                        config.key,
                        false,
                        "",
                        field.value
                      );

                      const inputBindings = createTextInputBindings();

                      return (
                        <div key={`${this.state.activeFields.key}-${field.key}`}>
                          <TextInput config={inputConfig} bindings={inputBindings}></TextInput>
                        </div>
                      );
                    })
                  }
                </div>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default DetailsPage;
```

**field.tsx**

```
export interface IFieldDefinition {
  key: string;
  value: string;
}

export interface IFieldConfigDefinition {
  key: string;
  dataType: IDataType;
  displayName?: string;
}
```

The **fields** have these values:

- input_field_name
- field_name
- datatype
- label

This is an example form.
when the user clicks the button, an empty form part like in the picture should display.

[image: example]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since I have only used react with hooks, I am not really sure how that code should work but, based on how you access the state in the render function, it looks like you can mutate the state adding the new value you want as follows:

```js
addField(newField = {}){
    this.setState({
      activeFields: {
        key: this.state.activeFields.key,
        fields: [...this.state.activeFields.fields, newField]
      }
    });
}
```

Notice I have initialized the prop `newField` to empty object, but you could pass other object with the structure you expect from the form.

Hope this helps!

Comment: just a little improvement, you can also use a function inside `setState` - 
`this.setState(state =>  do whatever is needed with current state)`

Comment: you can work with your state and then set it again.... `activeFields = this.state.activeFields` ... do a lot of things.... then `this.setState({activeFields})`